# Printing unicode character from number

Tags: python, unicode

In Python I'm trying to print out the character corresponding to a given code like this:

```
a = 159
print unichr(a)
```

It prints out a strange symbol. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Which unicode character did you expect to get?

Answer (score 2):

```
#To get numerical value of string. This gives me 49.
ord("1")

#To get string from numerical value. This gives me "1".
chr(49)
```

It is possible that the numerical value that you're trying to convert to a digit is the representative of a special character, in which case it is likely that python converted it into it's hex equivalent. To see the hex value of an integer:

```
hex(ord("1"))
```

If that is not the case, it's possible that it used another representative, since it is(hypothetically) a special character.

Comment: This does not explain why the OP is having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The character at unicode 159 is an Application Program Command. It's a control character, and is deemed *not a graphic character*.

[More information](https://codepoints.net/U+9F)